# Изучение Yii2 по офф гайду, проблема с БД

Tags: php, yii2, yii

В общем такая проблема, начал изучать Yii2 по тем документам что предоставляют разработчики и как дошел до этапа работы с БД, начались жуткие проблемы. 
Вот ссылка на гайд: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/start-databases

Собственно, проблема состоит в том, что всегда выдает 404 ошибку при обращении к той странице.
Вот код:

**Модель:**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class Countries extends ActiveRecord
{

}
```

**Контроллер:**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\Countries;

class EquipmentController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Countries::find();

        $pagination = new Pagination([
            'defaultPageSize' => 5,
            'totalCount' => $query -> count(),
        ]);

        $counries = $query->orderBy('name')
                ->offset($pagination->offset)
                ->limit($pagination->limit)
                ->all();
        return $this->render('index',[
           'counries' => $counries,
            'pagination' =>$pagination,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Представление:**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

?>
<h1>Devices</h1>
<ul>
    <?php    foreach ($counries as $counry):?>
    <li>
        <?= Html::encode("{$counry->code}")?>        
    </li>
    <?php    endforeach;?>
</ul>
<?=LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination])?>
```

**Подключение к бд:**

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',

    // Schema cache options (for production environment)
    //'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    //'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
    //'schemaCache' => 'cache',
];
```

Comment: Ну а роут-то где?

Comment: роут я так полагаю это параметр адресной строки:index.php?r=country%2Findex

Comment: Я не шибко шарю в yii но по строке `country/index` ищется контроллер `CountryController` с методом `indexAction`. У вас же я вижу `EquipmentController`. Не наводит на мысли?

Comment: оо теперь еще более интересно, Фреймворк умер с фатал крашем, ссылаясь на несуществующую модель

Comment: забыл добавить: use yii\db\ActiveRecord; но тем не менее другой краш, якобы не может найти таблицу countries

Comment: Ну а она есть, таблица-то?

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо. Проблема в том что я просто тупой кусок эникейщика. Извините что отнял ваше время

Comment: С тестовой базой получилось, теперь буду пробовать переносить этот алгоритм на свою базу с кучей таблиц

Comment: В общем с моей базой не получается, я грешу на кодировку. Попробую сейчас с разными таблица поиграть, и отпишу результат

Comment: в общем все это время была проблема с кодировкой, которая даже в конфиге.дб в yii не менялась

Comment: Если проблемы с кодировкой из-за cp1251, то надо бы наконец-то перейти на utf-8, а то муки Прометея дадут о себе знать.